# Simple Trigger SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm new in SQL Server, and I have to make a trigger to help me to insert data in my table.

I have 2 simples tables, **Test** and **Participant**. (id + varchar each one).
Test are already inserted.

In a 3rd table, **Inscription** I would like to make an entry with each test each time I add a student in my student table

The 3rd table would be like : id | FK_idTest | FK_idStudent

[image: Base­]

I'm not familiar with sql language, i'm currently searching how to do this action, and I ask here too.
I'll come back if I find something by myself. I'll also take a look in the trigger section.

Comment: No one here will write the code for you. You write the code, and if you run into problems, we will assist!

Comment: Students will be linked with all the tests. I was hoping i could use a for each to get all the tests then insert them in the 3rd table.

Comment: If the table will *always* have every student vs every test and no other fields then it doesn't seem like it serves a useful purpose... what do you intend to use this table for?

Comment: Triggers are a topic best addressed **after** you have mastered basic tsql.